# Understanding underscore bind

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
    function checkBalance() {
        return this.balance;
    }

    function Person(name, balance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }


    var me = new Person('tim', 1000);
    _.bind(checkBalance, Person);

    console.log(checkBalance()); //undefined
```

I know this is a case where checkBalance should be on the Prototype of the Person object, but I'm failing to understand why the bind method isn't working normally here.  I've tried both Person and me as the context for _.bind to bind checkBalance, but I keep getting undefined.  What's going on here that I'm getting this undefined?

Comment: try `_.bind(checkBalance, me);`

Comment: @Ejay I had tried that as well, the problem was that I wasn't setting `checkBalance = _.bind(checkBalance,me)`

Comment: we all miss the docs time to time :D http://underscorejs.org/#bind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bind(func, obj)` returns a new function identical to `func` except that `this` inside of the function will refer to `obj`.

You are binding `this` in the `checkBalance` function to the `Person` function, when it seems like you mean to bind `this` to `me`.

Try this:

```
var f = _.bind(checkBalance, me);
console.log(f()); //1000
```

Or, reassigning to the same function:

```
checkBalance = _.bind(checkBalance, me);
console.log(checkBalance()); //1000
```

Comment: I wasn't reassigning checkBalance, that's what the problem was.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie You might not even want to reassign to the same function. That could be confusing because you're essentially modifying the existing function rather than getting a copy that is bound the way you want.

Comment: So do you think it's better to have a variable that points to that function executing in a particular context rather than modifying the function itself?  If so, why?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Because if your `checkBalance` function is defined in the global scope (as it appears to be) you are actually modifying the globally accessible function. If that's really what you want to do, go for it. But I wouldn't do it if there's another alternative -- in your example, `function checkBalance(person) { return person.balance; }` would work fine -- because it could lead to some nasty bugs.

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't really leave that in the global scope, this was just a quick and dirty for demo purposes.  Although I do kind of like the idea of an object that manages the context that a function executes in.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Consider `function f(context, a, b, c) { ... }` where `f` uses `context` properties internally. Then you could say that the `context` object manages the context that `f` executes in. You can do this with the implicit `this` parameter and `_.bind(f, context)` with `function f(a, b, c) { ... }` and all usage of `context` replaced with `this`, but do that only if you have "a good reason to."